# Need help on error i keep getting in validation functions - pascal

Tags: pascal

This is my code

```
program val;
uses crt;

var
  UI:string;
  x:integer;
  error:integer;

begin
  repeat
  readln(UI);
  val(UI,x,error);
  until error = 0 ;
  writeln(UI)
end;
```

I get this error:

> > > validationfunctions.pas(12,9) Fatal: Syntax error, "." expected but "(" found

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `;` after your final `end` to a period (dot). (While you're at it, fix your indentation style to make the program flow clear.)

```
program val;
uses crt;

var
  UI:string;
  x:integer;
  error:integer;

begin
  repeat
  readln(UI);
  val(UI,x,error);
  until error = 0 ;
  writeln(UI);     { I added a missing ;, even though not required }
end.               { <-- fix this line - it is required}
```

Also, you've named your program `val`, and you're also trying to use the function `val()`. Naming your program the same as an internal function is a pretty bad idea. If you insist on doing so and the compiler you're using has issues, you can usually fix it by adding the unit name explicitly before the function call like `System.Val(UI, x, error);`.